# Exception in step at specflow

Tags: specflow

I'm calling in a function to step (specflow), 
Then(step's string)
and in step I throw an exception. I want to catch the exception with a different function and not in the step itself. Do someone know how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SpecFlow.
SpecFlow interprets an exception in an step as error and stops the execution of the Scenario.

What you can do, is to catch the exception in your step and save it in a field of the binding class. Then in the second step you can check this field.

like this:

```
[Binding]
public class BindingClass
{

    private Exception _exception;

    [When("an exception is thrown")
    public void ExceptionThrown()
    {
        try {
           .... //your code that throws an exception
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _exception = e;
        }
    }

    [Then("the exception has the message '(.*)'")]
    public void ExceptionHasTheMessage(string message)
    {
        if (_exception != null)
        {
            Assert.Equal(_exception.Message, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the **AfterStep** hook available in SpecFlow.

The code looks like this:

```
[AfterStep]

public void AfterStep()    
{
    if(_scenarioContext.ScenarioExecutionStatus.ToString().Equals("TestError"))        
    {
        Logger.LogScreenshot(exception, _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);   
    }
}
```

This piece of code will catch your exception and remaining steps will be skipped.